# What is Ubuntu's equivalent of Windows shell:startup?

Tags: 13.04

I'd like to automatically startup a few apps upon user login, where and how do I access this startup folder?

Comment: Take a look at Startup Applications, under Dash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open Dash

search for start-up

[image]

The start-up applications looks like

[image]

To add an application to the start-up press add button

[image]

Give it a name and write the command of your application and that's it